# how I can save different sub directory authentication data separately (even in chrome, Firefox or ...)?

Tags: javascript, authentication, autocomplete, difference

I have two different folders with separate logins for example:

`http://example.com/folder1/login
 http://example.com/folder2/login`

in both URLs Browser suggest me the other's authentication data?
how can I prevent this?
with javascript/html or server side or ....

Comment: By enforcing different username for each subdirectory. Browsers cannot save two passwords for same username.

Comment: You can try using different subdomains instead of subdirectory, that might work.

Comment: You can add the username and path in the auth cookie, and then check them against each other and the requested path. All done server side.